# Will querying firestore documents by an nested field scales?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, scaling

According to the Firestore current [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data), querying complex objects like nested lists does not scale.

From the text, i am not sure if object types are included.

To be more explicit, if i turn the structure on the documentation into the following, where the list is now an object

```
alovelace

    name :
      first : "Ada"
      last : "Lovelace"
    born : 1815
    rooms : { //only added brackets here to explicit show this is an object type field
              {"Software Chat":true},
              {"Famous Figures":true},
              {"Famous SWEs:true"}
          }
```

could the query "rooms.Software Chat"==true scale?
Or should i use compound keys, like "RoomPrefix + RoomName" for room references?

Notes:

- Rooms field will only store rooms links, not the rooms content.
- Room prefix is added just to prevent collisions when chat names have the same name as one of the document fields, e.g., chat name is "born"

Comment: The stated concern in the doc about scaling isn't related to query times.  It's related to the problem of lists that grow over time that make the document increasingly slow to retrieve.